# unprefixed attribute is giving error in style.xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbar sherlock for compatibility with android version >= 8 
and while using the code it gives me error

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'titleTextStyle'.
```

my code used in the xml is

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Change your minimun sdk verion from 8 to 11 and clearn and run your project

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the build SDK to at least API 11 (Honeycomb).

Answer (score 0):

I have experiment this issue too with `AndroidSherlock` `ActionBar`. EveryTime I change something inside style I get those erros to. Closing the the style file and `clean -> rebuild` fix tipically for me